# Salesforce Flows with Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

**Scenario:**

We have a multi-step flow made up from a number of lightning components, our first step contains a lightning:recordEditForm which creates some sobject and then passes the sobject into a variable in the flow for use in later steps.

**Issue:**

When navigating back to the first step the sobject variable seams to be cleared and so the record is not getting loaded into the lightning:recordEditForm breaking our flow.

**Question:**

Should this variable exist for the duration of the flow even when navigating back, if not is there an alternate approach to store the created record in order to maintain our flow?